# When to use BJT in differential configuration instead of op-amp

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, bjt

Why would one use a BJT differential amplifier configuration [such as this(these) one(s)](https://electrosome.com/differential-amplifier-transistors/) instead of an op-amp? Are there any pros and cons to both these circuits? I would maybe assume that a BJT amplifier might be cheaper and be used by companies to reduce costs, buy I'm not even sure if that is true.

Comment: Your link goes to a google search. This is like reverse psychology. - Wait what, when I clicked the link a second time it took me to the correct site.... Yeah this is why I hate links.

Comment: That is pretty much what is in most op amps for the front end

Answer (score 1):

If you want to build an amplifier from  discrete components. No, that isn't cheaper, because such input amplifier stage uses two matched transistors that were manufactured very carefully, like LSK389. They are used for low noise, high CMRR. So only special equipment, high end audio amplifiers, differential probes, sonar,...uses discrete build input stage amplifier.

Answer (score 0):

You can run differential BJTs at very low power, with VDD less than 1.5 volts.

Slowly.

Thus continuous monitoring may benefit from a discrete approach.

Answer (score 0):

The tanh input-output characteristics of a bjt based diff. pair offers a simple method for effectively converting a squarewave (some tenth of mV) into a relatively good quality sine wave - for a broad range of frequencies (in contrast to using a bandpass for this purpose).